# The time given to every thread whether the same or has a minimum time?

Tags: ios, multithreading

For example, in thread 1  there is executing something and it uses a global variable, but another thread may change this value

**thread 1**

```
a = 1;   
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       NSLog(@"a = %d", a);
});
```

**thread 2**

```
a = 2;
```

there are two questions,

1. if thread 1 executes first and can I assume system will always print a = 1? or system can change to thread 2 halfway and then change to thread 1 and get a = 2?
2. if I don't put NSLog in dispatch_asyc(), whether this cause different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't tell or guarantee exactly. You can assign the threads (or queues) priorities but you still don't know exactly what will happen.
2. Yes, logging will make a difference to the runtime, again you don't know if it might make a difference to the thread management.

So, if you need something to be protected from access by multiple threads then you need to protect it by adding some synchronisation. How you choose to do that depends on what it is and each case needs to be considered separately.